# iOS music replacement apps for iTunes match and dock connector for car radio

Tags: ios, itunes-match

My holy grail right now is an iOS music app that meets these two criteria

1. Supports iTunes Match
2. Works with my car's Made for iPod radio

Currently, I am using "Track 8", which supports iTunes Match but doesn't play nice with my car's radio. The app doesn't send any information to the radio about artist or song name. (Pandora on iOS does do this. Docked with my car, when Pandora is playing, the artist and track info appears on the radio LCD screen)

I need suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could email/tweet to the makers of Track 8 and tell them to use the [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) API, which is what Pandora and all music apps use to report track metadata.

Comment: I've contacted a couple devs. The answer I was provided is that Pandora and other similar apps have the option of "rolling their own" audio player. You can see this by looking in the multitasking tray with the play controls. What icon is shown? Apps which access iTunes Match are required to use the iOS music player. When using these apps the Music.app icon is next to the play controls. So, my holy grail does not exist.

Comment: So, over the weekend I downloaded my entire iTunes match library and uploaded it to Google music. Still can't control my library from my car radio, but I can browse and select songs on my device instead of being locked out, and get metadata on the radio display.

Comment: Last comment: apps that use the iOS music player are finicky when they're docked to my radio. They refuse to play any audio. My radio hijacks the music app. The radio wants to take control of the "iPod". The music app refuses to play any audio unless instructed to by the radio interface. Apps that roll their own music player like "Melodies" for Google music don't have this issue. This is a 2012 Camaro, using the same radio from 2010. I plugged my wife's iPod in and it works fine. Music stored locally on the device works fine as well. iTunes Match is not easy to work with.